# How to change the work directory with the remote development extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using this extension : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack to work on a development remotely and it's very cool !! :)

But, How to change or define work directory ?

e.g : When I connect me on a server I am redirect to my work directory by default (~) but I would like to define my work directory to `/var/www/html/domain/code` for example.

Thank you in advance ! :)

Answer (score 5):

Go to File -> Open Folder while connected with remote

Add your path in the text box and click open. It may ask for your user password again and the directory will be changed.

It's tiring but the only solution.

You can use the terminal also to navigate to folders but it won't
open folders in VScode but in terminal you can use:

```
Terminal ->New Terminal
```

Comment: Hi and thank you :) Hmm... I have this error message : "Please enter a path that exists." . Yet this folder exists. May be the permissions. On this server I can go to folder with the nginx user. It is possible to do `sudo su - <username>` or equivalent ?

Comment: 1. Are you entering the path right ,  do pwd on linux based systems to get the path    2. if on server you are able to access that path with the same user details , then you should be able to access it like this

Comment: Yes I define the path right. But my user is not able to access that path... I think is not possible to do a `sudo su - nginx` when I connect myself on the server and open folders in VSCode ?